# Static file referenced by handler not found: index.html

Tags: google-app-engine

After deploying my first app engine app, I'm receiving `Static file referenced by handler not found: index.html` as an error in the logs. Here is my yaml file:

```
application: section-14
version: v1
api_version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /bower_components
  static_dir: bower_components
- url: /general
  static_dir: general
- url: /projects
  static_dir: projects
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
- url: /styles
  static_dir: styles
- url: /elements
  static_dir: elements
- url: /images
  static_dir: images

#here's the problem
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: /
#------------------

- url: /elements.html
  static_files: elements.html
  upload: /
```

I can travel to any of the other directories, and files located in those directories, without any problem. Also, if you look below the `index` entry, the `elements.html` route works also.

I noticed in other projects that people are defining a `/static` directory. Is that a requirement? My local environment serves this app without any issues as is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Naming the directory `static` isn't a requirement. I do it because it makes the significance of the layout obvious (to me, at least).

Here's an `app.yaml` fragment from one of my apps that has a static home page and static assets.

```
handlers:
- url: /style/
  static_dir: static/style
- url: /js/
  static_dir: static/js
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico
  mime_type: image/x-icon
- url: /.+
  script: main.app
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
```

The order is significant, as is the use of `/.+` instead of `/.*` With the latter, requests for `/` would get routed to the `main.app`

Edited to add: Having a url mapping for a static `favicon.ico` is useful to prevent the request getting routed to your app, since this'll cause App Engine to spin up an instance when one isn't needed.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer, but I wanted to highlight that changing: `upload: /` to `upload: index.html` is what solved the issue.