# Ignore GCP /_ah/ handlers

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform

This React website is served on Google Cloud Platform

I want to edit an existing handler

```
  - url: /(.*)$
    static_files: public/\1/index.html
    upload: public/.*/index.html
```

to get rid of warnings like this `Static file referenced by handler not found: public/_ah/start/index.html`

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459385/handling-ah-start-route-nodejs-at-google-app-engine) solution, but I'm not quite sure how to use it in my case. Any ideas?
I tried option below, but it didn't work, build fails.

```
  - url: /(?!.*\/_ah).*$
    static_files: public/\1/index.html
    upload: public/.*/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

An error in an application's app.yaml frequently causes the error static file referenced by handler not found. It basically means that one of app.yaml's static file handlers is diverting to a file that does not exist or is named wrongly.

You might be able to come up with a strategy if you have a technique of differentiating files from directories. You can achieve something like this by stating that all filenames must have extensions (and folders most not. in their names):

**/optional/path/folder/ - serve index.html inside**

```
- url: /(.*)/ 
 static_files: public/\1/index.html 
 upload: public/.*/index.html
```

**/optional/path/name.extension => files - serve them**

```
- url: /((.*\/)*[^\/]+\.[^\/]+)$ 
 static_files: public/\1 
 upload: public/.*
```

**anything else is a folder - serve index.html inside**

```
- url: /(.*)$ 
 static_files: public/\1/index.html 
 upload: public/.*/index.html
```

Remember that all this depends on your directory.

Here is also [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref) and [structuring web services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuration-files) documentation that could help.

Comment: It doesn't help at all. I have these handlers.

Comment: Searching for more documentation or a solution for your issue, I found the following link related to the same error message you are getting, the solution shows the full app.yaml with a brief description. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482884/static-file-referenced-by-handler-not-found-index-html
And as you can see in the comment section, upload: / to upload: index.html is what solved the issue.